# Qt with Visual Studio macro issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, windows

I want to open my Qt project in Visual Studio for more advance debugging. The problem is it not recognize one defined constant from Qt pro file.

Code Qt pro file:

```
QMAKE_TARGET_NAME = My App Test
DEFINES += APP_NAME=$$shell_quote(\"$$QMAKE_TARGET_NAME\")
```

Works normal in Qt IDE. In Visual Studio 2015 displays error - user-defined literal operator not found (`#define APP_NAME ""My App Test""`).

So how to make it compatible with Visual Studio 2015 and Qt? The problem is with wrong escape, in Visual Studio it displays double quotes around My App Test (`APP_NAME` constant). How to escape properly? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe try to remove the double quotes inside the barracks?

Comment: I have changed to DEFINES += APP_NAME=$$shell_quote($$QMAKE_TARGET_NAME).It shows 70 errors in Qt and 1 in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to create C++ header file with APP_NAME constant and include it where it requires. Now it's compatible with Qt and Visual Studio 2015.